# How to move a layer using a slider control?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-scripting

I'm trying to create a mogrt file that has the option of moving a layer using a control (instead of just moving it on the timeline).

Is there a way to create a slider control for example that allows to adjust some kind of "offset"?

Comment: Do you mean adjusting the region in time, or in position?

Comment: In time. I really want to be able to move a layer from 00:05:00 to 00:07:00 with a slider. Not sure if it would be possible, that's why I am asking :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, in short. But you will need to learn Expression Controls.

Search YouTube for "Expression Control Slider After Effects"

There are a lot of good tutorials which will walk you through the process.